# Am I allowed to bring an unopened wine bottle in my carry-on luggage onto an airplane?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, alcohol, prohibited-items

I am aware that many airports have duty-free shops which sell liquor.
Obviously, if you are allowed to buy liquor at an airport duty-free shop,
you should be able to carry the liquor
on the airplane to your intended destination.

However, can I buy a 750 ml wine bottle
not from the airport duty-free shop,
but say from the supermarket,
and bring it on board an airplane in my carry-on luggage?
Or do I have to check-in my wine bottle?

Comment: To be clear, if you buy it at the duty free, then yes. If you buy it outside the airport, then no, it won't fly. It would have to be checked.

Comment: NO, you can't bring a bottle in your hand luggage.

Comment: @I Like to Code No - liquids, aerosols, gels, creams and pastes in your carry-on bag are limited to travel-sized containers that are 3.4 ounces (100 milliliters) or less per item. Liquids in containers larger than 3.4 ounces or 100 milliliters in checked baggage. All that would happen is that your 750ml bottle of wine would be confiscated at the screening desk and join the large pile of other confiscated items.

Comment: Yes, you can bring a wine bottle onboard, unopened or open.  You can buy liquor or wine in terminal before departure.  Unfortunately, it is far more likely for a wine bottle to be confiscated at the terminal entrance than a reasonably dangerous item.

Comment: My son was at the airport one of those times someone forgetful was trying to bring a bottle of vodka through security, and rather than surrender it to TSA was offering shots to everyone in line.

Answer (score 9):

No. You cannot. There is strict control over liquids and you can only pass security with 100ml bottles.  Since carry-on must pass through security, you cannot have a 750ml bottle with you.

When you buy Duty-Free at the airport or even non duty-free, you buy them *past* security and they are items the airport considers secure.

There is a subtlety which may even make the airport refuse to sell it to you. When you buy from duty-free you show your passport and boarding pass, if they know that based on your itinerary you will have to make it through security again, many shops will refuse to sell you large bottles. This happened to me several times. Last time when travelling from Taipei to Quito via San Francisco, the duty-free in Taipei did not let me buy liquids since I would  have to clear security in San Francisco. Now, I have also seen some airports allow sealed duty-free items bypass security when changing terminals that also require a security check. This varies by airport and terminal.

Comment: While this is the correct answer for international travel, there are countries like Australia & Japan that do permit liquids on domestic flights.

Comment: That was pretty lame of them, because you could have checked your bag at SFO before security.

Comment: It happens often, not just for that itinerary, it is just that they are not aware if the luggage will be transferred by hand or handled by the airport.